# CSS 'background-size: contain' property for IE8 and lower

Tags: css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [make background-size work in IE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/make-background-size-work-in-ie)

I'm looking for an IE8 and lower solution for the css background-size property. Now I came across this post, but the problem is that it basically only covers:

```
background-size: cover;
(stretching over the whole element)
```

and not

```
background-size: contain;
(fitting 100*100% of the image inside the element)
```

Here is the IE solution:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='images/logo.gif',
sizingMethod='scale');

-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='images/logo.gif',
sizingMethod='scale')";
```

Now there are other values for sizingMethod, they are crop and image, but still does not creat the desired effect([see why](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532920%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))
What is the possible solution for background-size: contain ? I know there is a jquery plugin for that, but I would prefer to use a more css-based method if possible

Thanks!

Comment: don't know why you closed it, I'm actually referencing to the link you added as a 'duplicate'...that solution only covers background-size: cover, and not contain...

Comment: the code I used here is the code from that post you are referencing to

Comment: yeah seems like a pretty silly close. You could click the reopen link to allow > 3000 rep to reopen..