# loading js function from another file

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a javascript like that

```
$.fn.hasBorder = function() {   
  if ((this.outerWidth() - this.innerWidth() > 0) ||  (this.outerHeight() - this.innerHeight() > 0)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
};

function removeImage(){
$(document).ready(function() {
  var selectedImgsArr = [];
   $("img").click(function() {

      if($(this).hasBorder()) {
          $(this).css("border", "");
          //you can remove the id from array if you need to
      }
      else {
         $(this).css("border", "1 px solid red");
         selectedImgsArr.push($(this).attr("id")); //something like this 
         alert(selectedImgsArr);
 }
   });
```

I load this script to  my page. In order to use this script

i wrote this

```
div load="removeImage">
```

What it does not work ?

Comment: Do you have jquery included?  Do you really have a div without a starting `<`?  Are you getting any errors?  Please take some pride in your question and provide more details than just the code.  The HTML snippet where you include the JS would also be useful.

Comment: It is time to learn what is unobtrusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `load` on your `div` you can't use `document.ready` on the script. Because if you do it that way what you are saying is: "On div load event register a listener that will execute when the page is ready". But… that event was fired before register the listener.

Also you can't use `onload` on a `div`, just on `body`.

In short, do it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var selectedImgsArr = [];
   $("img").click(function() {
      if($(this).hasBorder()) {
          $(this).css("border", "");
          //you can remove the id from array if you need to
      } else {
         $(this).css("border", "1 px solid red");
         selectedImgsArr.push($(this).attr("id")); //something like this 
         alert(selectedImgsArr);
      }
  });
});
```

And remove the `load="removeImage"` from your HTML.

Comment: Not quite true: Registering a listener to document's ready event fires the listener immediately even after the original onload event has been triggered.

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking of the "onload" event. But that can only be used on the "body" element. And even if that worked you would have to write it like this "...="removeImage()".

There ware similar questions here on SO, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057236/how-to-add-onload-event-in-div) explains how to put a "onload" on a "div".