# javascript onload not working but onclick is working css draw line

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add onload event to a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057236/how-to-add-onload-event-to-a-div)

I am trying to draw a line with css and javascript as in the example here: [example](http://www.gapjumper.com/research/lines.html%20). I can get it to work just fine with the original stuff but after trying to modify it and then get it to work onload from the html onload equals its not working, but it is working with the onclick event.

here is my css:

```
.line 
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 0px;
    border-width: 2px 0px 0px 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #99aadd;
 }
```

and the javascript:

```
function createLine2(myline,x1,y1,x2,y2)
{
    if (x2 < x1)
    {
        var temp = x1;
        x1 = x2;
        x2 = temp;
        temp = y1;
        y1 = y2;
        y2 = temp;
    }
    var length = Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2)+(y1-y2)*(y1-y2));
    myline.style.width = length+"px";
    var angle = Math.atan((y2-y1)/(x2-x1));
    myline.style.top = y1 + 0.5*length*Math.sin(angle) + "px";
    myline.style.left = x1 - 0.5*length*(1 - Math.cos(angle)) + "px";
    myline.style.MozTransform = myline.style.WebkitTransform = myline.style.OTransform="rotate("+angle+"rad)";
}
```

and finally the html that does not work:

```
<div class="line" onload="createLine2(this,100,100,0,0)">test</div><br>
```

and the html that does work:

```
<div class="line" onclick="createLine2(this,100,100,0,0)">test</div><br>
```

How do I get it to work with onload and what did I mess up?

Comment: DIVs do not have a load event

Comment: A simple googling of "div onload" would have given you the answer.

Comment: @musa then how could i get it to create the line in that div onload

Comment: Why is this tagged jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The onload Event is not allowed on div Tags. It's only allowed with the following tags:

```
<body>, <frame>, <frameset>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, <link>, <script>, <style>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery, I suggest using the jquery ready function.

> .ready( handler ) handlerA function to execute after the DOM is ready.

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

If you are using plain JavaScript, use window.onload

> window.onload = funcRef;

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onload