# Javascript AJAX on a dynamicly loaded div?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

[How to add onload event to a div element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057236/how-to-add-onload-event-to-a-div)

I've read this, despite this I have a problem..
I know there's no `onLoad` for divs, but I should be able to execute a snippet like so:

```
...
<div id="content">
    <div class="text">
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    navigate('main.php', 'content');
</script>
....
```

This doesn't work, if I start a new browser session and navigate to index.php, it shows me a login window. After logging in it redirects me to index.php but with some session variables and cookies set. Now index.php contains the code above, prior to this `content` didn't exist.

Now to my issue: it appears as if most browsers refuses to accept that `content` exists,
in the navigate function I've got:

```
function navigate(str, what) {
    if(what == null) {
        what = document.documentElement;
    } else {
        what = document.getElementById(what);
    }
```

what will become `null` because it's a not a valid Element at the moment of execution.

I've tried:

```
window.onLoad = naviate('main.php', 'content');
```

Which does nothing, same issue there..
Also tried putting the `<script>` block at the end without luck.

I can't use jQuery or anything so please keep it to standard Javascript, HTML and CSS.
Browsers in use: IE8, Chrome, FireFox.

---

1. Load index.php
2. Login to loginwindow
3. Load index.php
4. Upon completed load of index.php, read all elements including `content`
5. Update `content` with some AJAX data.

### It works if

I login, load the page once with unsuccessful result and then refresh the page again.

### And here's the reason why:

I use AJAX on the login window as well, it uses `navigate()` just as all my buttons and what not does. So the issue is that `index.php` gets loaded, with a login window, that login window updates the entire page with AJAX (javascript) which in turn, tries to call `navigate()` again from within the return data from the AJAX call...
**The "inline" `navigate()` gets called!!!**, it's just that it doesn't know all the elements because it's load via AJAX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
window.onload = function(){
    navigate('main.php', 'content');
}
```

Comment: (I've tried it but) that makes no difference, `navigate(..)` is still being called as it should, problem is still that it's executed before the browser is aware of `content`, which renders a `null` value.

Comment: is `content` created dynamically ?

Comment: Yepp, it is. This is what probably confused both my answers. Updated the question accordingly.

Comment: I've also tried a delay timer, which, some what helps but still not enough.

Comment: In this case your ajax script should allow a callback after he is finish. 1-load content, 2-interact with content

Comment: Well it doesn't i'm afraid. Loading content dynamicly causes the browser to not recognize `content` since it's dynamicly loaded almost as the same time as the actual content.

Comment: Should not that adding a `timeout` on the `what = document..` works, but I'm having issues with that since i can't delay the AJAX code since the dynamicly loaded content uses it as well so i'll just delay everything..

Comment: Not really a 100% functional solution because of the stupid way i loaded my content, but placing all java inclusions at the bottom of the page after all the data is fetched helps.

Comment: I think you really should manually add a callback argument in the ajax method (s), that would save you from headaches and allow you to only interact after everything is dynamically added. Keep in mind that if you try to save time at the beginning but loose it all later, you didn't save time.

Answer (score 0):

According to my tests you can get div element by `.getElementById` even before the page is loaded.
Do not forget that the `navigate` function must be defined before it is called. So if you have your scripts at the end of document (which is correct), you must call the function after execution of theese scripts.

But anyway, you've assigned the `.onload` function wrongly. Do it like this:

```
window.onload = function(event) {
                /*any script here*/
}
```

Or like this:

```
function load(event) {
                /*any script here*/
}
window.onload =load;
```

Comment: As commented on the other solution, i've tried this already. Same effect, the issue is **not** that navigate(...) isn't called, because it is. The issue is that window.onload tries to access `content`. I'll update my question to REALLY explain the issue.

Comment: Then the issue is somewhere else. I made you a [simple script](http://u8.8u.cz//crap/divonload.php) to prove that, if everything is done how you state it, the script works.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, my hosting (unlike localhost) buffers output, so you cannot se the `content` div filled 3 seconds before page is loaded.