# onclick= , onrun= "jQuery Code"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

is something like this possible?

`<div id="box1" onload="$("#box1").addClass("fadeIn");"></div>`

The script does not seem to run when the document loads. I know that declaring a function beforehand and then using it on load works like below. Are you able to write javascript/jQuery instead of a function like I have tried above?

`<div id="box1" onload="myFunction();"></div>`

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057236/how-to-add-onload-event-to-a-div

Answer (score 4):

Try adding to the document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#box1").addClass("fadeIn");
});
```

There may be other ways to do it, but from what I've found this is probably the most reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Do it dynamically using the `.ready()` method ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)) or using the `.on()` method ([docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)). The ready method will execute the code as soon as the DOM is ready. The `onload` will execute as all assets are loaded (images for example).

```
$('#box1').ready( function() {
  ...
} );

//--or--

$( document ).ready( function() {
  $('#box1').on( 'load', function() {
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may or may not work. When Your browser run every `onload`, jQuery may not been initialized. Better use jQuery directly in `<script>`.

Answer (score 0):

`DIV` elements do not have an `onload` event. But knowing when the element is loaded is easy, since the browser loads the DOM synchronously.

Just put the script right after the closing tag and it’s done:

```
<div id="box1"></div>
<script>$("#box1").addClass("fadeIn");</script>
```