# knockout event, which is called when loading an element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-mvc

Prompt please knockout event, which is called when loading an element.

Example:

```
<div data-bind="<my_event>: onPopupShown ">  </div>
```

Comment: we have a Popup and function must be called by its opening. But it is in another file. How to call a function when a Popup shows?

Comment: do you want to call certain function on click of div?

Comment: you should use data-bind = "click: onPopShown"

Answer (score 0):

There is no onload event for divs. BTW It's not a knockout event per se, knockout is simply a convenient wrapper for DOM events.

Only elements which load external resources such as images and scripts have an onload event.

Using some ideas from this link: [How to add onload event to a div element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057236/how-to-add-onload-event-to-a-div) Perhaps you could use the YUI on and a custom knockout binding?

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/event/#onavailable