# Using a String as HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to create a news box for my website today and I have a problem. Let me explain what happens. I create a 2d array that contains the news (date and the news). I then loop through it to construct the news_string and then use that for the DIV's innerHTML. I have put a very simple version of it below

```
for (var i = 0; i < news.length; i++) 
{
news_string.concat(news[i][1],"<br>");
}

document.getElementById("news-content").innerHTML = news_string;
```

However nothing appears. I have cut it down to the very minimal. No result. I have used alerts. Nothing appears. The news_string is blank regardless of the fact I put data into it. And even if I do gain a string nothing appears in the DIV box. What's causing this massive break?

Comment: Did you try `alert(news.length)`?

Comment: I did alert(news.length) and it is all normal.

Comment: However if I do this.

news_string = news_string + news[i][1] + "<br>";
alert(news_string)

The string completely appears

Comment: @JeremyBeare: Strings are immutable in JavaScript. `news_string.concat` returns a new string, so the code in your loop isn't really changing anything.

Comment: What about using `news_string = news_string.concat(news[i][1],"<br>");` ?

Comment: Alright, so the string is now fixed. It shows up in the alerts. But it still won't appear in the innerHTML (Thanks for the info regarding concat)

Comment: It not should be like `res = news_string.concat(news[i][1],"<br>");`? and findally `res` should append as `innerHTML`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**concat method**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat) returns a value, you have no variable assignement there to catch it...

From the docs (notice the bold part):

> The concat() method combines the text of two or more strings **and returns a new string**.

So you should use:

```
news_string = news_string.concat(news[i][1],"<br>");
```

Comment: Oh, pfft, how did I not notice that?

Comment: Or just `news.map(function(thing) { return thing[1]; }).join('<br>')`.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Can't believe I made that error. So the string now has values. However the problem still persists that the innerHTML is blank. This is the code I pass into the innerHTML

document.getElementById("news-content").innerHTML = news_string;

Comment: @JeremyBeare, please post a sample of the array.

Comment: news[0][0] = new Date(2012,12,14);
 news[0][1] = "This is a test string";
 news[1][0] = new Date(2012,12,27);
 news[1][1] = "And so is this!";

Comment: @JeremyBeare, you are defining your array in a strange/wrong way. Is that really your code? Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/exzgc/

Comment: It is for testing purposes. I dumbed it down to the real basics.

Now this is interesting. I may have found the problem. I did an alert on the news-content div and it didn't even give an alert. So I did it on another piece and its HTML appeared. This made me think at the time of using the function, the news-content div doesn't exist.
<br/><br/>
So now I have moved the trigger of the function to the div

<div id="news-content" onload="loadNews();"></div>

And it won't load now. Posting the source now (See below)

Comment: [Main Script](http://www.thelegenaseries.com/main_script.js)
[When the Page is loaded (see "news-bar" div)](http://www.thelegenaseries.com/main_script.js)
[News Box](http://www.thelegenaseries.com/news_box.html)

Comment: @JeremyBeare `onload` is not made for div at all

Comment: @JeremyBeare, you cannot add onload to a div... Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057236/how-to-add-onload-event-to-a-div

Comment: Based on the fact that the loadNews() function has no parameters. How should I proceed?

Comment: @JeremyBeare, here is a idea. A second parameter, that is ignored if not there. Put it in the sucess function you have, after the innerHTML part. Example: __http://jsfiddle.net/JEcV4/1/__

Comment: Well now the function is triggered. All I need to do is get the function to wait until the content-canvas innerHTML has been loaded. [See loadPage()] (http://www.thelegenaseries.com/main_script.js). Any ideas? (And thanks everyone for the help. I'd have never guessed all this had a play into it breaking)

Comment: @JeremyBeare, the `func && func();` part should be the line after this one: `document.getElementById("content-canvas").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;`

Comment: I did that and the last part of the func won't occur. And as well as that, the page won't load either. [See Script](www.thelegenaseries.com/main_script.js)

alert(document.getElementById("news-content").innerHTML);

Comment: @JeremyBeare, it works for me now(!): http://www.thelegenaseries.com/ - do a refresh and it should work for you also.

Comment: @JeremyBeare, now you commented the important line(!)... I see `//document.getElementById("news-content").innerHTML = news_string;` in your code. Remove the `//`

Comment: @JeremyBeare, in the inline javascript remove the `()`. refer just to the function `loadNews` in the parameter without the `()`. I missleaded you in my fast example before sorry. Check here: __http://jsfiddle.net/C7nh3/__