# Animation in JS won't move

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been several hours trying to make a `<div>` block move left via JavaScript, then go back to original position. Not a chance.

This is the code:

**JS**

```
var block= null;

function init() {
    block= document.getElementById('myDiv');
}

function move() {
    block.style.left =  parseInt(block.style.left) + 10 + 'px';

    if(parseInt(block.style.left)>=600) {
        block.style.left = 12;
    }

    setTimeout(move,20);
}

window.onload = init;
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="myDiv"  onload="move();">
    <img src="image.png" id="anImage" >
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#myDiv {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40%;
    left: 100px;
    border: 3px solid black;
}
```

What you see in the code are all the elements (and their styles) involved in this. The js file is loading correctly and works with other functions (changing the image inside the div, etc...).

If you see any mistakes I made please point them to me. It's my first moving animation and it can't just make it work.

Ps: It should work just with this so I'm not going to use jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `move();` to your `init` function:

```
function init() {
  block= document.getElementById('myDiv');
  move();
}
```

Change your `move()` function as follows:

```
function move() {   
  block.style.left =  parseInt(block.offsetLeft, 10) + 10 + 'px';

  if(parseInt(block.offsetLeft, 10)>=600) {
    block.style.left = '12px';
  }

  setTimeout(move,20);
}
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zws8gkdv/)**

Comment: Aaand this totally worked. Marking it as solution asap. Thank you.

Comment: Use radix parameter with parseInt

Answer (score 1):

No, `onload` cannot work over a `DIV` element.
Put `move()` inside the init function, but also:
use `requestAnimationFrame` when possible, otherwise set a setTimeout to `1000/60`ms (~60FPS), you can use `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` to retrieve the `.left` position.
To store the initial position (100) you can memorize the value directly inside your element Object using a custom property:

```
var block= null;

function rect(el){
  return el.getBoundingClientRect();
}

function init() {
  block = document.getElementById('myDiv');
  block.initialLeft = rect(block).left; // Store original position
  move();
}

function move() {
  var left = rect(block).left + 10;
  if(left>600) left = block.initialLeft; // Reset to initial value
  block.style.left = left +'px';
  return requestAnimationFrame(move) || setTimeout(draw, 1000/60);
}

window.onload = init;
```

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/kopano/3/edit?html,css,js,output)***

Comment: I really need to ask, why is it so necessary to move the move() function into the init? I mean wouldn't the "onload=move();" into the <div> call the function anyway? PS: Also, thanks for the alternative solution.

Comment: Great call on `requestAnimationFrame` (and the rest).  However, I would stick with `offsetLeft`, because it's much faster than `getBoundingClientRect()`:  http://jsperf.com/getboundingclientrect-vs-offsetwidth/22

Comment: @Melferas, `div`'s don't have onload events.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057236/how-to-add-onload-event-to-a-div-element

Comment: @Melferas The onload event can only be used on window, document, frames, images, and scripts. I forgot to remove it from the HTML cause I did not even noticed it :)

Comment: @RickHitchcock ohh... great find! Thanks for sharing (about perf. rect/offs)

Comment: @RickHitchcock Oh that's why... Silly me. Thanks a lot :) I've learnt a lot today.