# How to call a javaScript function inside a div after specific time?

Tags: javascript

Here, the scenario is i want to make a javascript function call inside a div after  specific time ..But How do I implement it using javascript/ajax?

```
<div class="container" function()>
</div>
```

Comment: See `setTimeout` in JavaScript

Comment: Div's do not have an onload event either

Comment: divs do not have an `onload` attribute; what are you trying to do?

Comment: I see your ajax tag: Please clarify: Are you asking how to trigger a function call after an ajax response has been received? Or something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add onload event to a div element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057236/how-to-add-onload-event-to-a-div-element)

Comment: Why it's important to have a script _in_ a div? The placing of a script usually  doesn't matter.

Comment: Actually I want to reload the div after specific time , so when it reload it called a ajax function which will load the update data..so it's my problem in details..So if you have a better solution, you can suggest ..

Answer (score 0):

Divs don't have an `onLoad` handler. One thing you can do is to quickly and dirtily put a script tag under your `div` like so:

```
<div class="container">
</div>
<script>
 setTimeout(function() {
    //Do what you want to do
}, 5000)
</script>
```

Comment: Ah my bad. I thought it was `onClick` Made the change

Comment: Is there anyway I could call that function automatically after specific time inside the div

Comment: What does "inside the div" mean. You tagged the question "ajax" - please update the question with the scenario you have in mind

Comment: @mplungjan I think you wanna put this comment under the original question