# Canvas content is not showing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Good day,
I have a problem with the canvas. I'm using boostrap and I'd like to show some graphics. I have this:

```
<div id="charts" class="tab-pane fade">
  <div class="container-fluid-charts onload="init();">
    <div id="container1" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;border: 1px solid black;background-color: white;"></div>
      <canvas id="chart1">Your browser cannot display the charts...</canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

The Javascript is composed like this:

```
function init() {
    var c = document.getElementById("chart1");
    var ctx1 = c.getContext('2d');

    drawChart1();
}

function drawChart1() {
    ctx1.moveTo(ctx.canvas.width / 2 , 0);
    ctx1.lineTo(0, ctx.canvas.height);
    ctx1.stroke();

    ctx1.beginPath();
    ctx1.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx1.stroke();

    ctx1.font = "30px Arial";
    ctx1.fillText("Hello World",10,50);
}
```

I have no errors showing and the canvas is empty. I think it's related to the DOM... Anyone can help me please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You declare the local variable `var ctx1 = ...` within the context of the `init()` function. You cannot access it outside that function. Thus, accessing `ctx1` within `drawChart1()` fails.
- Also, within `drawChart1()`, you are accessing a `ctx` variable which hasn't been declared anywhere.
- You are missing a quote closing the `class="...` attribute.
- Also, the `<div>` element doesn't support the `onload` attribute: [How to add onload event to a div element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057236/how-to-add-onload-event-to-a-div-element)

A better solution is to pass the context `ctx` as a parameter to the `drawChart1(ctx)` function. Placing your script below all relevant DOM elements makes the `onload` handler superfluous:

```html
<div id="charts" class="tab-pane fade">
  <div class="container-fluid-charts">
    <div id="container1" style="width: 100%; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto;border: 1px solid black;background-color: white;"></div>
    <canvas id="chart1">Your browser cannot display the charts...</canvas>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  function drawChart1(ctx) {
    ctx.moveTo(ctx.canvas.width / 2, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(0, ctx.canvas.height);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(95, 50, 40, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.font = "30px Arial";
    ctx.fillText("Hello World", 10, 50);
  }


  var c = document.getElementById("chart1");
  var ctx = c.getContext('2d');

  drawChart1(ctx);
</script>
```

Comment: If I follow your example, I have an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getContext' of null"

Comment: @EricF Did you change the canvas ID or declare the script before the canvas element? Does above snippet run fine?

Comment: The snippet works fine... I didn't change anything. That's why I was wondering if it was related to the DOM. Something like ctx.getElementById('container')[0];  or something like that... Not sure...

Comment: Sorry I cannot because of sensitive content... :( But the code I posted above is the original version. I'll find another way then. Thanks a lot for your help anyway ! I appreciate it.

Comment: @EricF `ctx.getElementById('container')[0];` <-- `ctx` doesn't have a getElementById method, only `document` has - and the return value is an individual element, not an array unless you call e.g. getElement**s**ByTagName.

Comment: Makes sense... I tried many options with no success... Oh well... Thank You again !