# Change CSS display value in-line on page load

Tags: javascript, html, css

Inline in the HTML (without using a separate javascript file or code block) how to change display of element on page load? I want it to go from display:none back to default.

I've tried this:

```
<div style="display:none" onload="function(){this.style.display = 'block'}">
   hello
</div>
```

And this:

```
<div style="display:none" onload="this.style.display = ''">
    hello
</div>
```

But doesn't work, thanks.

Comment: There is no `onload` event for `div`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057236/how-to-add-onload-event-to-a-div-element

Answer (score 2):

As I wrote in comment under question, there is no `onload` event for `div`.

You can use this code, it changes the `div`s `display` value when document is loaded.

```js
document.onload = document.getElementById('div').style.display = 'block';
```

```html
<div style="display:none" id="div">
   hello
</div>
```