# Displaying clock in div with javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, selectors-api

I'm getting grey haired here because I can't get this clock to display on my SPA. I'm haveing a clock that should be displayed on the page but I can't seem to get it right. I have tried the things we were taught at the course but I can't seem to get it right. Could you please take a look at it and lend a hand perhaps. Not even the console.log is printed out.

Code in Clock.js:

```
function clock () {
  let now = new Date()
  let h = now.getHours()
  let m = now.getMinutes()
  let s = now.getSeconds()

  m = checkTime(m)
  s = checkTime(s)

  let target = document.querySelector('#footer-clock')
  let clockText = document.createTextNode(h + ':' + m + ':' + s)
  target.appendChild(clockText)

  setInterval(clock, 500)
}

function checkTime (i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = '0' + i
  }
  return i
}

module.exports = clock
```

Code in app.js:

```
const clock = require('./clock.js')

document.querySelector('#footer-clock').onload = function () {
  clock()
  console.log('Loaded')
}
```

And in HTML I have:

```
footer>
  <div id="footer-clock">

  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add onload event to a div element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057236/how-to-add-onload-event-to-a-div-element)

Comment: Beyond the onload issue, you are also appending a new timestamp every invocation of `clock`. Instead you might just want to do `target.textContent = h + ':' + m + ':' + s`. Further, you call `setInterval`, which will make the invocations explode. You probably want `setTimeout`.

Comment: https://fiddle.jshell.net/v1yjftoj/

Comment: @Roy Works fine, now I just need to get to load when the page is loaded...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser doesn't understand what

```
module.exports = {}
const clock = require('./clock.js')
```

this will work when you use something like [webpack](https://webpack.js.org) for bundling and using commonjs Module 
also if you look at the console in devtools in chrome you will see this error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

note that : when you developing sites using html you should put any scripts in the script tag 
like this

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="clock.js"></script>
```

now the code in **clock.js** will be available any where so in 
**app.js** you can call the method without require function

```
clock()
```

also you need to use **window.onload** instead of

```
document.querySelector('#footer-clock').onload = function () {
clock()
console.log('Loaded')
}
```

[here you can learn more about global events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload)