# Moving a div back and forth / animation using javascript

Tags: javascript, function, object, animation

hi i'm trying to get a div element to move back and forth automatic but i'm stuck i am not sure what i need to add to get it to work. i cant even get it to move at all

my namespace:

```
var $hubbe = {};
```

my move function:

```
$hubbe.movex = 0;

$hubbe.newdiv = document.getElementById("newdiv");

$hubbe.move = function() {
    $hubbe.movex++
    $hubbe.newdiv.style.left = $hubbe.movex + 'px';
    setTimeout($hubbe.move, 2000);
}
```

and the div :

```
$hubbe.printelement = function() {
$hubbe.div = document.createElement("DIV");
$hubbe.div.setAttribute("id", "newdiv");
$hubbe.div.setAttribute("onload", "$hubbe.move()")
$hubbe.div.innerHTML = "hej";
$hubbe.div.style.position = "absolute";
$hubbe.div.style.left = "50%";
$hubbe.div.style.top = "50%";
document.body.appendChild($hubbe.div);
}
```

edit:
my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g7ytvevp/

Comment: Can you please make a https://jsfiddle.net/ for that? ... it would be much easier to solve that way.

Comment: oh yes ofc sorry i'm a bit tired forgot about that. i added it now.

Comment: i dont think the element onload will work, try to call the move function immediately after you add it on the document

Comment: im really new to javascript how do i that? haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the following: 
https://jsfiddle.net/g7ytvevp/1/

`<script> 
        var $hubbe = {};`

```
    $hubbe.printelement = function() {
        //skapar en varibale $hubbe.div som ett div element
        $hubbe.div = document.createElement("DIV");
        // sätter ett id newdiv på $hubbe.div
        $hubbe.div.setAttribute("id", "newdiv");
        $hubbe.div.setAttribute("style", "background-color:red;")
        $hubbe.div.innerHTML = "hej";
        $hubbe.div.style.position = "absolute";
        $hubbe.div.style.left = "50%";
        $hubbe.div.style.top = "50%";
        //skriver ut $hubbe.div till body
        document.body.appendChild($hubbe.div);
        $hubbe.move();
    }

    $hubbe.movex = 0;
    $hubbe.newdiv = document.getElementById("newdiv");
    $hubbe.move = function() {
            $hubbe.movex++
                $hubbe.div.style.left = $hubbe.movex + 'px';
                setTimeout($hubbe.move, 2000);
    }
</script>`
```

You "move" function wasn't being called because the "onload" event wasn't being fired for that div. The reason for that is mentioned in this post:
[How to add onload event to a div element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057236/how-to-add-onload-event-to-a-div-element)

UPDATE:

The final version of the animation with descriptive comments.
https://jsfiddle.net/g7ytvevp/9/

```
    var $hubbe = {};

    $hubbe.printelement = function() {

        $hubbe.div = document.createElement("DIV");

        $hubbe.div.setAttribute("id", "newdiv");
        $hubbe.div.setAttribute("style", "background-color:red;")
        $hubbe.div.innerHTML = "hej";
        $hubbe.div.style.position = "absolute";
        $hubbe.div.style.left = "50%";
        $hubbe.div.style.top = "50%";

        document.body.appendChild($hubbe.div);
        $hubbe.move();
    }

    $hubbe.movex = 0;
    $hubbe.newdiv = document.getElementById("newdiv");
    $hubbe.translateX = 1;
    $hubbe.translateY = 0;
            $hubbe.move = function() {
                    var element = $hubbe.div;
            var translateX = $hubbe.translateX;
            var translateY = $hubbe.translateY;
            // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect
            // This method basically gives us the position of all four sides of the "element" on which it is call. It gives us the size as well.
            // In the current case we only require the 'current position' 
            // of our div so we call it over our div and the resultant
            // variable 'pos' would contain the  respective position of 
            // each side left / right / top / bottom in it e.g pos.left etc.
            // This is needed because we need to keep track of where our div
            // currently is, since the translation is based on certain 
            // conditions e.g if the div reaches the right edge off the 
            // screen, it should start moving left etc.
                    var pos = element.getBoundingClientRect();
            // We're using the same method to find the dimesions of our 
            // parent container i.e "body" element, since we need to keep
            // track of the condition when our div reaches the edge of the 
            // screen and that we can only know if we know the co-ordinates
            // of the edge.
                    var domRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();

            if(pos.right >= domRect.right)
                $hubbe.translateX = -1;

            if(pos.left <= domRect.left)
                $hubbe.translateX = 1;
            // This is the line that basically makes the translation along
            // X - axis happen. pos.left variable contains the position
            // (in pixels) of the left edge of the div object. We add the
            // translation factor "translateX" (1 in this case) to it and 
            // update the position of the div, causing it to move to the left
            // or the right. In case of a positive (+1, +2 ... ) it will move
            // to the right, for negative, it will go left and for 0, it will
            // not move along X - axis. The higher the translation factor, 
            // the faster the object would translate.
                $hubbe.div.style.left = pos.left + translateX + 'px';
            // This can be used for vertical translation / movement along the 
            // Y - axis. It was just for demonstration purposes. For now
            // it isn't event being used. 
            $hubbe.div.style.top = pos.top + translateY + 'px';
                setTimeout($hubbe.move, 10);
    }


</script>
```

Comment: This seems like an interesting approach as well: 
https://codepen.io/frankDraws/pen/rxaPzQ

P.S Don't forget to approve and upvote :D

Comment: @mikael Anwar yes but i need to do it in only js :) ofc i have already upvoted but my votes do not show because i'm new here:) another question how do i get it to start from the middel? and if i want it to stop moving after like 500px and start going the other way how do i do that? like the one in your codepen?

Comment: @SebastianAndersson Please check the updated jsfiddle. I have implemented everything.

https://jsfiddle.net/g7ytvevp/7/

For starting in the middle you simply set position from top and left to 50%, something that you have already done.
For stopping it at a certain point, or changing the direction of translation we simply compare the current position of the element with the position where we want that change. Once the condition is fulfilled we simply alter the translation factor of the object.

Comment: @Mikael Anwar thank you so much for the help. You saved my night. and thank you for the description i learned alot:)

Comment: @Mikael Anwar another question when i look through the code i se many things like getBoundingClientRect()  that i have no ide what it is and what dose the domRect variable do?. if you have the time could you do some comments on those parts ?  i did some comments with questions in the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/g7ytvevp/8/
thank you in advance

Comment: Most welcome! I have update the jsfiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/g7ytvevp/9/