# How to get id of element from onload

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a reason why the alert says undefined is loaded?

```js
function test(object) {
  var id = object.id;
  alert(id + " is loaded");
}
```

```html
<body id="test" onload="test(this);">
  <h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
```

​

Comment: Have you tried put the script before /body ?

Comment: Interesting will try

Comment: This might work with img onerror https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057236/how-to-add-onload-event-to-a-div-element

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript, the `this` on the `onload` event on body refers to `window` instead of `body`.  However, the `onload` on image elements (and `iframe`) refers to the element itself.  To get around this, I would change your code to:

```
test(document.body)
```

## Proof of how `onload` works JavaScript:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function test(object) {
  console.log("" + object);
}
</script>
</head>
<body id="test" onload="test(this)">
<img src="https://www.google.org/assets/static/images/logo_googledotorg-171e7482e5523603fc0eed236dd772d8.svg" onload="test(this)" />
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

"this" in your onload function will refer to the window object, not to the body element itself. In your onload function, you'll need to do a getElementById('test') to get the body's id.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer window.onload than document.body.onload because it is less obtrusive. But, both however are the same.

```js
function test(object) {
    var id = object.id;
    alert(id + " is loaded");
}
window.onload = function(){ test(document.body); }
```

```html
<body id="test">
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
</body>
```

I moved the onload event to the JavaScript.