# calling javascript function inside html element and jinja2?

Tags: javascript, flask, jinja2

i have this code:

```
{% for review in reviews %}
   <div>
     {{ review.content }}
       by {{ review.username }}
       - timeDifference("{{ review.date_submitted }}")
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

on the 5th line is a js function timeDifference that will return time difference in text, I want to insert js function there, how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Execute Js function like that is not possible. And what possible is during onload time execute the javascript function and do DOM manipulation.

***In Html***

```
<-- In for loop -->
<div onload="timeDifference( {{ review.id }}, {{ review.date_submitted }} );">
  <p id="timeDifferenceElement{{ review.id }}"></p>
</div>
```

***In Javascript***

```
function timeDifference(id, date_submitted) {
  const timeDifferenceElement = document.getElementById("timeDifferenceElement" + id)
  // Do calculation
  ---
  timeDifferenceElement.innerHTML = "something from the calculation"
}
```

Comment: hi, just wondering, I am doing it in a loop, i have confusion how to reference the element?

Comment: Oh.. Let me modify the example then.

Comment: @iamgpbaculio Changed the example in the answer. Let me know if you have any additional questions'

Comment: i have tested it but suddenly the function on onload isn't firing :/

Comment: Wait I made the mistake there. Please see the update

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution that worked for me, inspired by Raja Simons' answer and [How to add onload event to a div element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057236/how-to-add-onload-event-to-a-div-element):

```
<div id="review{{review.id}}">
   {{ review.content }} by {{ review.username }}
     -
   <p id="timeDifferenceElement{{ review.id }}"></p>
   <script type="text/javascript">
    timeDifferenceForDate( '{{ review.id }}', '{{ review.date_posted }}' );
   </script>
```