# Why is my javascript method not being called?

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

I have this in my HTML body:

```
<script src="{% static "jquery/sessionExists.js" %}"></script>

{% if context.alreadyOnSession == 'YES' %}
    <h5 class="loginerror" onload="advSessionExists()">This session is already logged in</h5>
{% endif %}
```

These `{}` are django code.

sessionExists.js:

```
function advSessionExists(){
    console.log('Just checking if its triggered');
}
```

Also I tried by putting my JavaScript code raw in the HTML body with `<script type=text/javascript></script>`, and also I tried with `onbeforeprint` instead of `onload` but it is still not showing my JS method.

`The <h5> is being showed`, but not triggering my JS method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The onload event can only be used on the document(body) itself, frames, images, and scripts. In other words, it can be attached to only body and/or each external resource. The div (or h5) is not an external resource and it's loaded as part of the body, so the onload event doesn't apply there.
>
> Via - [How to add onload event to a div
>   element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057236/how-to-add-onload-event-to-a-div-element#4057251)

---

To invoke the function when your `<h5>` element has loaded, just call the function right after the `<h5>` element within your django `if statement` like this:

```
{% if context.alreadyOnSession == 'YES' %}

    <h5 class="loginerror">This session is already logged in</h5>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      advSessionExists();
    </script>

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add `onload="advSessionExists()` to `script` tag. Or write in your script `window.addEventListener('onload', advSessionExists);`