# Is it possible to call function when HTML element gets loaded?

Tags: javascript, html

For example if I have in my body following

```
<button id="start"></button>
```

Is it possible to define in the HTML code a JS function that will be called when this element is loaded/shwon? So for example I can set some value of this element in JS? I know I can do in JS getElementBy... but that would be in the opposite direction I'm wanting to achieve this.
If yes, is it then possible to access the id of this html element in the called function?

Comment: I think you are looking for a [mutationobserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver)

Comment: I guess at some point you create/show those elements. Why don't you act there directly?

Comment: I have an answer, but can't answer the question :( Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tp4Loykb/ You will need to open the console.

Comment: I posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55106785/9325419) on the duplicated question, maybe it can help you

Answer (score 2):

```
var startNode = document.getElementById('start');
var observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
   if(startNode.style.display !='none' ){
        //when DOM is visible
   }else {
        //when DOM is hidden
   }
});
observer.observe(startNode,  { attributes: true, childList: true });
```

You can just use `MutationObserver` to observe the changes for specific element.

Comment: the  callback first parameter of the mutationobserver is a list of changed nodes.

Comment: This also wont detect when the element is added to the DOM.