# Is there an equivalent of onload (or a hypothetical onparse) for standard HTML <elements>?

Tags: javascript, events, element, onload

I am loading some markup into a page, asynchronously, using Ajax.

I want to attach an `EventListener` to an `<element>` within that markup, such that ***when the element is parsed*** the `EventListener` fires.

What `Event` can I use for `myEvent` ?

- `onparse` does not exist
- `onload` *does* exist, but we can't apply it to `<h2>` or `<div>`. We can only apply it to:

  - `<body>`
  - `<frame>`
  - `<iframe>`
  - `<img>`
  - `<input type="image">`
  - `<link>`
  - `<script>`
  - `<style>`

Are there any other candidate `Events` I might use?

Or any alternative approaches to ensuring that an `EventListener` fires when an element is parsed?

---

The best approach I have come across so far (albeit a little bit unorthodox) is the

- `<img src>` hack

An `<img>` with an undeclared `src` attribute will trigger the `onerror` `EventListener` **when it is parsed**.

Consequently the following example works:

```js
let myHeadingLoadEventTrigger = document.getElementById('my-heading-load-event-trigger');

const updateHeading = (e) => {

  let myHeading = e.target.previousElementSibling;
  
  if (true) { // <= CONDITION HERE
    
    myHeading.textContent = 'My Updated Heading';
  }
  
  // Modern alternative to document.body.removeChild(e.target);
  e.target.remove();
}

myHeadingLoadEventTrigger.addEventListener('error', updateHeading, false);
```

```html
<h2>My Heading</h2>
<img id="my-heading-load-event-trigger" src />
```

---

## Solution:

Although a native `onparse` event does not exist, I can:

- write my own `onparse` event; and
- use a custom `data-onparse` attribute to fire the `onparse` event

**Working Example:**

```js
// Create (homemade) parse event
let parseEvent = new Event('parse');

// Create Initialising Function which can be run at any time
const initialiseParseableElements = () => {

  // Get all the elements which need to respond to an onparse event
  let elementsWithParseEventListener = document.querySelectorAll('[data-onparse]');
  
  // Attach Event Listeners and Dispatch Events
  elementsWithParseEventListener.forEach((elementWithParseEventListener) => {

    elementWithParseEventListener.addEventListener('parse', updateParseEventTarget, false);
    elementWithParseEventListener.dataset.onparsed = elementWithParseEventListener.dataset.onparse;
    elementWithParseEventListener.removeAttribute('data-onparse');
    elementWithParseEventListener.dispatchEvent(parseEvent);
  });
}

// Callback function for the Parse Event Listener
const updateParseEventTarget = (e) => {
  
  switch (e.target.dataset.onparsed) {

    case ('my-heading') : e.target.textContent = 'My Updated Heading'; break;
  }
}

// Run Initialising Function
initialiseParseableElements();
```

```html
<h2 data-onparse="my-heading">My Heading</h2>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202293/discussion-on-question-by-rounin-says-je-suis-monica-is-there-an-equivalent-of-o).

Comment: @Quintin, the dupe is very old and could use a new solution as OP came up with himself which is why I retracted my vote earlier