# Change HTML <p> tag with JavaScript on Flask variable load

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I'm trying to change the text within a `p` tag on load using JavaScript, using the first character of that `p` tag. The `p` tag is populated using Flask double curly brackets syntax, i.e `{{yourstring}}`.

A variable is calculated in Python and either a 1 or 0 is returned and then added to a string at index 0. That string is then pulled into the HTML as the `{{trailing_check}}` variable.

I want my js function to change the value in that first index to say 'tick' or 'cross' (will later be an image) based on whether the value is a 1 or 0.

However, nothing seems to be happening... please see my code below.

HTML

```
<div class="summary" onload="good_outcome()">
   <p id = "trailing_check">{{trailing_check}}</p>
</div>
```

JS

```
function good_outcome(){
   if(document.getElementById("trailing_check").innerHTML.charAt(0) == '1'){
     document.getElementById("trailing_check").innerHTML = "tick"
   }
   else{
     document.getElementById("trailing_check").innerHTML = "Cross"
   }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Move the logic to the document onload event handler.

Answer (score 0):

> The `onload` event can only be used on the `document(body)` itself,
>   frames, images, and scripts. In other words, it can be attached to
>   only body and/or each external resource. The div is not an external
>   resource and it's loaded as part of the body, so the onload event
>   doesn't apply there. [Check this answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057236/how-to-add-onload-event-to-a-div-element)

You should add the function call to Document ready function:
So your Div will not have the onload as shown below:

```
<div class="summary" >
   <p id = "trailing_check">{{trailing_check}}</p>
</div>
```

And the JS changes to run `good_changes()` at Document load:

```
`$( document ).ready(function() {
    good_outcome();
}
```

If you are not using the Jquery, You can also attach the same function to DOMContentLoaded event:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', good_outcome, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `div` elements do not support the `onload` event. To fix this you have to run your script after the document  has finished loading by listening the document `DOMContentLoaded`event to know when it is loaded or just move the onload to the `body` element.

If using the `body` element just do

```
<body onload="good_outcome()">
   ...
</body>
```

And by listening the `DOMContentLoaded` event in JavaScript

```
<div class="summary">
  <p id = "trailing_check">{{trailing_check}}</p> 
</div>
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
   if(document.getElementById("trailing_check").innerHTML.charAt(0) == '1'){
     document.getElementById("trailing_check").innerHTML = "tick"
   }
   else {
     document.getElementById("trailing_check").innerHTML = "Cross"
   }
  });
</script>
```