# how can I set onload event using div in html

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, onload

I have this code which works for me using "onlick" functun.

```
onload="gh_success()"
```

Now i want to use the same function "Onload".

How can I call this on page load?

This is the initial code

```
     <td><button class="btn btn-success" onclick="gh_success()">SHOW ME</button></td>
```

I tried

```
  <script>
    window.addEventListener("load", gh_success)
  </script>
```

but the notification I am trying to call via

```
function gh_success() {
  Lobibox.notify('success', {
    pauseDelayOnHover: true,
    continueDelayOnInactiveTab: false,
    position: 'center top',
    showClass: 'rollIn',
    hideClass: 'rollOut',
    icon: 'fa fa-check-circle',
    width: 600,
    msg: 'Your Withdrawal request has been successfully placed,'
  });
```

didn't come up

Comment: A div element doesn’t have an onload method. What’re you trying to do? Sounds like an XY problem to me.

Comment: `window.addEventListener("load",gh_success)`

Comment: "didn't work" is not a great problem description

Comment: I have edited it

Comment: Try with <button class="btn btn-success" onclick="gh_success()" onload="gh_success()">

Comment: If you want page load, then why don't you use `<body onload="gh_success()">...</body>`.

Comment: You can't use onload with div. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4059124/9155456

Comment: `window.addEventListener('load', gh_success);` should work just fine.