# How to change $(document).ready (function) to onload special tag in order to pass variable to js function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

Each of them supposed to show a value from database when the page loads. So I wrote three `$(document).ready(function)` with three input for `GET` controller value. I know they run parallel maybe it is good but I want to see if I wrote only one function (design it Linear) with an input value to pass to `GET` method, I get higher performance or not.

I change the code bellow :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetData',
        data: { id: 1 },
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (result) {
            $('#result1').html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

to

```
function bringData(statusId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetData',
        data: { id: statusId },
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (result) {
            $('#result1').html(result);
        }
    });
};
```

and in my view I use `onload="bringData(0)"` like bellow :

```
      <div class="inner">
            <h3 ><span id="result1"  onload="bringData(0)"></span><sup 
            style="font-size: 20px"></sup></h3>
            <p>Commited Orders</p>
        </div>
```

but when I run the code it doesn't show the value?

Comment: Is there any error message in browser console when you use second method?

Comment: In console I don't see any error. I put debugger in my jquery code but  It doesn't even go into the function.

Comment: @Phuzi already proved a correct answer. Here is another way of linking an action with the loading state of each individual  DOM element: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057236/how-to-add-onload-event-to-a-div-element .

Comment: @fahime abouhamze, yes, I was just about to tell you that you can't add onload in `<span>`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onload` is not a [global attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes) you can't just stick it on any element and expect it to work.

What you should have done was call `bringData` from the ready function:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    bringData(0);
});

function bringData(statusId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetData',
        data: { id: statusId },
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (result) {
            $('#result1').html(result);
        }
    });
};
```

If you insist on using an `onload` attribute, then it should be on the `<body>` tag

```html
<body onload="bringData(0)">
    ...
</body>
```

Comment: I wrote the first part for bringData(0) and bringData(1) two times. It is better than copy the whole code. But Isn't there a way to call bringData(1) or bringData(3) in my view or better say call function and pass the input value in the view? @phuzi. I'll just want to make the less code but high efficient performance.

Comment: You already have `bringData` that you can call with any statusId i.e. `bringData(7632)`. It sounds like you have another problem now.